# simpy store capacity left

Tags: python, buffer, simpy

I am trying to find out how can I know how many items are currently stored in a buffer using Simpy. In my situation there is a machine that produces items and next they are stored in a buffer with limited capacity (2). So if the buffer is full, the machine should stop working.

```
    global t1
    global t2
    
    with machine.request() as req:
      yield req
      if len(buffer.get_queue) >= 1:
        yield env.timeout(t2 - t1)
```

```
machine = simpy.Resource(env,capacity= 1)
buffer = simpy.Store(env,capacity=2)
```

I tried to use `len(buffer.get_queue)` , but this always returns 0. I have not been able to find another way to return the number of items which are stored in the buffer.

- t2-t1 is the time it takes for an item to leave the buffer after it has entered the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The current items in a buffer can be returned by `buffer.items`

Comment: len(buffer.items)